# Trello: assign due dates to a checklist item?

Tags: trello

I would like to be able to assign due dates to checklist items in a card, but do not see a way to do this. I have read through the guide. Suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: In future, have better titles that actually say what the question is and refrain from posting signatures

Comment: Here's the card in the Trello development board: https://trello.com/c/p2D8Zlxd You can vote there, I think it will be even more effective than voting on this question :)

Answer (score 1):

Due dates are only at the card level right now, but as with member assignment, it might be nice to have them at the checklist item level.